# Writing a formula in a cell that checks if two cell values are equal but making one exception

Tags: excel

I am trying to make a list that compares two cells in the same row, in two different columns of a table and check whether the values are the same. I am facing a Problem when the value of one cell is 0 and the other cell is empty. I used the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(AND(H6=N6;P6="Matched A");AND(P6="Matched B";H6=N6);AND(P6="Shared";H6=N6);AND(P6="No Match";N6=H6));"Yes";"No")
```

Whenever the value of one cell is 0 and the other cell is empty the result of this formula is TRUE. How could I change the formula so that this is considered an exception or the returned value is FALSE.

I thank you in advance and all help is welcome.

Comment: The title had a grammar mistake and I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another condition into your `AND()` clauses: compare lengths of empty cell value and zero:

```
AND(H6=N6;P6="Matched A";LEN(H6)=LEN(N6))
```

Length of empty cell value is `0` while length of `0` is `1`.